# Why do I have extremely low loss but accuracy is 0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a model to classify 3 classes of images using Tensorflow. Currently I am using the box standard ResNet50 definition:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(203,147,256))
model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights=None, input_tensor=input_layer, classes=3
```

Here is my model compilation:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), #default learning_rate=0.001
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```

Having split my data using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`, I instantiate Tensorflow Dataset objects:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val))

train_ds = train_ds.batch(2)
val_ds = val_ds.batch(2
```

And begin training:

```
history = model.fit(train_ds,
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    epochs=200,
                    verbose=2)#verbopsity 2 means no one line per epoch
```

When training, I am severely overfitting, but that is an issue for later. My issue now is that my training loss is extremely small, but my training accuracy is 0 or near zero. Here is the final training epoch:

```
Epoch 200/200
33/33 - 3s - loss: 4.4143e-06 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.5500 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

I thought that Tensorflow calculates accuracy based on the training loss. I have absolutely no idea why my accuracy is zero if my loss seems so well. Am I using the proper loss and metrics? Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Any help is appreciated

Addendum:

My training labels are one hot encoded, and my training and validation confusion matrices are below, respectively:

```
[[23  0  0]
 [ 0 21  0]
 [ 0  0 22]]

[[0 0 7]
 [0 7 2]
 [0 0 7]]
```

(I know I am super overfitting, but that is a problem for later)

I am starting to think there is something wrong with the metric itself, because I think the training classification looks pretty good

Comment: No, accuracy and loss are independent values, it is likely that the labels of your model are incorrect, you could include label information and model output.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will edit the question. The weird part is the training confusion matrix looks really good

Answer (score 1):

That's because `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()` works different. It checks if predicted values match with the corresponding labels. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/metrics.py#L3981-L3988) if you want to check that.

Under the hood, `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()` calculates `tf.equal(y_true, y_pred)`. In your case `y_pred` contains floating point numbers whereas the labels (`y_true`) are one hot encoded integers.

Consider the case:

```
y_pred = array([0.5403488 , 0.24064924, 0.219002  ], dtype=float32)

y_true = array([1., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

Well, if you check the result of `tf.equal(y_true, y_pred)`, it will yield only `False` values.

In your case, you should either use `metrics = ['accuracy']` or `metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]`.

Comment: @Daniel Sherman Answer helpful?