# CNN accuracy: 0.0000e+00 for multi-classification on images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have the following code that produces my horrible accuracy dilema, has anyone else encountered this issue for multi classification task(49 different images to classify)?

I am running resnet50 on top of my CNN model with **softmax as last activation FN**, my **loss is categorical_crossentropy** and my **optimizer is Adam**.

What might I be doing wrong?

```
## Build CNN architecture
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=1, input_shape = (720, 720, 3)))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=1, padding="same"))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model1.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=1, padding="same"))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=1, padding="same"))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(200))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Dense(200))
model1.add(Dropout(0.24))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Dense(49, activation='softmax')) 

model1.summary()

# Image data generator for on the fly image augmentation
directory = '/home/carlini-TF2/data/train/'
batch_size = 64
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=90.,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=[0.8,1.2],
        horizontal_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.2,
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=directory,
                                                    subset='training',
                                                    target_size=(720, 720),
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    seed=42,
                                                    color_mode='rgb', 
                                                    class_mode='categorical', 
                                                    batch_size=batch_size)
valid_directory = '/home/carlini-TF2/data/test/'
valid_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=valid_directory,
                                                    target_size=(720, 720),
                                                    color_mode="rgb",
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    subset='validation',
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    seed=42)

## Compile and train Neural Network 
METRICS = [
        tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name='accuracy'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')]

# optimal optimizer FN | loss FN to work with accuracy metric
model1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
               optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
               metrics=METRICS)

# stop training when loss gets worse after consecutive epochs
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3) 

# fit model with augmented training set and validation set | shuffle batch 
history = model1.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data = valid_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n//batch_size,
                    validation_steps = valid_generator.n//batch_size,
                    shuffle=True, callbacks = [callback],
                    epochs=50)
```

Comment: Which part are you getting the accuracy value from? `fit()`? `evaluate()`? `predict()`?

Comment: @Djinn I am getting the accuracy value from training(fit()), the mode has the same value 0.0000e+00 after each epoch.

Comment: Try lowering your learning rate, 1e-3 can be pretty large, especially when having to deal with 49 classes (or a lot of input data). `model1.add(Dense(200)); model1.add(Activation('relu')); model1.add(Dense(200))` is redundant. Without an activation function, `Dense`'s default function is linear, where `a(x) = x`. I don't think that's your issue specifically. Also your callback isn't doing anything. It needs a `min_delta` to know how much change to check for. Is the dataset too large for memory all at once?

Comment: @Djinn Intresting, I lowered the learning rate but now my loss has grown almost exponentially larger. Also I am training on roughly 16K images before on the fly data augmentation and am sure my system has enough memory w/r to batch_size. Do you see any fatal flaws with my implementation?

Comment: With 49 classes, a high starting loss is to be expected. Asking about the memory helps because if you can load everything in memory, that's one less issue you'll have to worry about with generaliation.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71755080/why-do-i-have-extremely-low-loss-but-accuracy-is-0/71757897#71757897 help? `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` works different than you think.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that ResNet50 was being used for data augmentation and not in the CNN architecture. In order to reach somewhat robust model the following code is needed.

We can throw out the previous architecture and use a very simple model and the ResNet50 since this gives conclusive results.

We must use Functional API since ResNet50 was built on it

```
data_bias = np.log(1802./4657) 
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(data_bias)

resnet50_imagenet_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(720,720,3) )
resnet50_imagenet_model.trainable = False

#Flatten output layer of Resnet
flattened = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(resnet50_imagenet_model.output)

#Fully connected layer, output layer with 49 diff labels
fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(49, activation='softmax', bias_initializer=initializer, name="AddedDense2")(flattened)

model1 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=resnet50_imagenet_model.input, outputs=fc2)
```